# React scroll on dialog material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to use  [React Scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/blob/master/examples/basic/app.js), but I have a problem.

I'm using it on a `Dialog` component from Material UI, the scroll only works on the body, and not on the `Dialog`.

```
var Link = Scroll.Link;
var Element = Scroll.Element;
var Events = Scroll.Events;
var scrollSpy = Scroll.scrollSpy;

componentDidMount() {
    Events.scrollEvent.register('begin', function (to, element) {
        console.log("begin", arguments);
    });

    Events.scrollEvent.register('end', function (to, element) {
        console.log("end", arguments);
    });

    scrollSpy.update();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Events.scrollEvent.remove('begin');
    Events.scrollEvent.remove('end');
}

public render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            <Link activeClass="active" to="upload" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500}>Upload</Link>
            <Element name="upload">
                <UploadZone onupload={this.props.onCreateDocument} onsuccessupload={this.uploadedfile} lastfileupload={this.props.lastuploadfile} clickable={true} />   
            </Element>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I call this component in a dialog on application component, the parent component.

So I would like to scroll on the `Dialog`, and not on the body.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'containerId' prop. ID name should be added to container responsible for scrolling. In case of Material-ui's dialog - DialogContent component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use containerId prop as @Demiurg77 said. I tried with paper scroll mode and code below worked for me.

```
<Dialog fullWidth={true} maxWidth={'lg'} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open} scroll={'paper'}>
    <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
        Settings
    </DialogTitle>
    <Link className={section1} to={section1} spy={true} smooth={true} duration={250} containerId={'dialogCon'}>To Section 1</Link>
    <DialogContent id='dialogCon'>
        <DialogContentText id={section1}>
            <Typography gutterBottom>
                Some Text
            </Typography>
        </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```